# How to generate month by month starting with a given index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

So...I'm trying to generate 12 months starting by a given month, but using a for loop (0-11). After that, each number will be converted in the corresponding month name. But my issue is in that *for loop*.

What I've done so far is the following:

```
const startMonth = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  const month =
    i + startMonth < 12 ? i + startMonth : startMonth - i - 2;
}
```

So, this will generate 12 months starting with February and ending with January. It also work for startMonth=0, that will generate 12 months starting with January and ending with December.

However, the second part (the *else* clause) of this approach is wrong. It does not work for the rest of values. Any ideas how to adjust the for loop to make it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adjust the value with [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) and `12` to get a value between  zero and smaller than `12`.

```js
const startMonth = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    console.log((startMonth + i) % 12);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```